# Filling circles in lattice scatter plot by condition

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I have the following code:

```
require(lattice)
data <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,2,3,4,5), y = c(5,1,4,6,1,7), 
                   color = c("red", "red", "black", "blue", "yellow", "red"))
data$size <- data$x*data$y*0.2
xyplot(data$y ~ data$x, xlab = "x", ylab = "y", cex = data$size, ylim = c(0,11), xlim = c(0,6))
```

As you can see, this gives scatter plot with conditional sizing of circles. What I want to do is to fill the circles by condition as well (coloring provided by `data$color`). I tried to use `fill` option, but it fails to give me what I want. I will appreciate any suggestions on how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can set the `pch` argument to be solid circles.

```
library(lattice)

xyplot(data$y ~ data$x, xlab = "x", ylab = "y", cex = data$size, ylim = c(0,11), xlim = c(0,6),
       col = data$color, pch = 19)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. What if I want some circles to be empty (i.e., only circle border drawn) while others filled? How can I modify color variable to accomplish that?

Comment: Ok, I just figured it out, the trick is to provide variable that stores different types of pch for each point. Thanks again for the help!